# How to diffentiate the webservice request is from android app?

Tags: android, web-services, user-agent

I am new to android and working on an application,I am making the webservice request from android app and website,I want to track that webservice request whether it is coming from mobile app or website?So is there  any way to differentiation it from the webservice request?Without using "user-Agent" in the header or without adding any value explicitly?

Comment: what is the problem with user agent?

Comment: @PratikPopat -Hello Pratik,Thank you for quick reply,No problem with user agent,But i want to know is there any other way without putting some value explicitly?pleaase help me if any ways to do so.

Comment: you can send an extra parameter in your api indicating user agent yourself

Comment: you should take two values in existing parameters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*want to track that webservice request whether it is coming from mobile app or website?*

- You need to add one parameter in request header and define your device type there and same thing should be read at the server end.

Comment: Jigar, You have to pass something that can be traced out at server end for user type bifurcation.       

You can aslo add basic authentication which will have different credentials for Mobile and Web.

Answer (score 0):

First, construct an API that will service the request between the user and the client. Then test using jsonlint or Postman to determine the JSON key-value pairs..

Comment: thanks for response,But i think you are not getting my question properly,I already buit api and making request.